# alternative to ruby aws-s3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, installation

Is there alternative to ruby aws-s3.
I've installed aws-s3 (gem install aws-s3) but got error when i run my script

```
ruby s3Metadata.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in    
'gem_original_require': /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.1.4/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:183:  
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '|' (SyntaxError)   
        define_method(sym) do |*args, &block|    
                                     ^   
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.1.4/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:192: syntax error,    unexpected kEND, expecting $end  from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems   /custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'    
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.1.4/lib/builder/xmlmarkup.rb:14   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in    'gem_original_require'   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'   
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/builder-3.1.4/lib/builder.rb:12   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in    'gem_original_require'   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in 'require'   
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:159:in    'require_library_or_gem'   
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3.rb:12   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in    'gem_original_require'   
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require'   
    from s3Metadata.rb:4`   

s3Metadata.rb:4   = `require 'aws/s3'
```

Googled it but no solution....
I need to run script to update/add some metadata in amazon S3.

`aws-s3 (0.6.3)`
have old version of ruby `ruby 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [x86_64-linux]`
I can't upgrade it will mess up a lot of stuff. Is there a solution or alternative to ruby aws-s3?

Answer (score 2):

[The Rightscale AWS gem](https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws) also has s3 support.

Comment: do you know if it will have any **conflict** with aws-s3 since it is used by my app already but for some reason gives that error when i try to run my script?

Comment: It won't conflict, per se - you can use both (though you shouldn't).  However, they have completely separate APIs so code written for the aws-s3 gem will not execute against the rightscale gem.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides their own gem called [`aws-sdk`](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk). I can't promise it works in 1.8.6, with such an ancient version of Ruby I think your best bet is installing a very early version of any gem, since many will have moved to 1.9 in more recent versions.

Comment: The aws-sdk gem is regularly tested against 1.8.7, but not 1.8.6.  There is definitely some 1.8.6 unfriendly code.